# For To-Do list : unable to U00D7 to right side closing the list

Tags: javascript

I am unable to move "close" to the right side.

I have tried float:right, right:0, align-content:right in css but nothing seems to work.
*index.html*

```
<head>
<style>
.close{
right:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
<input type = "text" size = "35" id="work" placeholder = "Enter your list here">
<input type="submit" onClick="appendToDoList()" value="Add to List">
</div>
<ul id="workUl">
<li>Work out</li>
</ul>
<script>
//include a close button for list 
    var getList= document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<getList.length; i++){
        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var closebtn = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
        span.appendChild(closebtn);
        getList[i].appendChild(span);
    }

    //add to the list   
    function appendToDoList(){
    var ListN = document.createElement("li");
    var N = document.getElementById("work").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(N);
    ListN.appendChild(t);
    if (N === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
    document.getElementById("workUl").appendChild(ListN);
  }
   document.getElementById("work").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<close.length;i++){

  }
  ListN.appendChild(span);
}
```

The close button should be align to the right side. Could you please suggest something. I also went through the similar post in past, however it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet, it will help you to get a solution faster than if everyone has to set up a fiddle or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a well structured code. I have create a fiddle with 2-3 minor corrections and the close "button" seems to be on the right side (https://jsfiddle.net/x1kf8mz6/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div> 
    <input type = "text" size = "35" id="work" placeholder = "Enter your list here">
    <input type="submit" onClick="appendToDoList()" value="Add to List">
  </div>
  <ul id="workUl">
    <li>Work out</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//add to the list   
    function appendToDoList(){
    var ListN = document.createElement("li");
    var N = document.getElementById("work").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(N);
    ListN.appendChild(t);
    if (N === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
    document.getElementById("workUl").appendChild(ListN);
  }
   document.getElementById("work").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<close.length;i++){

  }
  ListN.appendChild(span);
}
```

and finally CSS:

```
.close{
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the "position" absolute for span tag and position "relative" for li tag. Then it will definitely work.

Answer (score -2):

Try add this in CSS (for me it worked, if i understood your question)

```
    ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; //you can change the icon distance (**for example:**just add like 5em, the *close* icon will come closer)//
  top: 0;
}
```